# How to enable Automatic file download in Windows 10 Settings?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

My `Automatic file downloads` setting is disabled, how to enable it? 
[image: <code>Automatic file downloads</code> setting is disabled]

Comment: Doesn't it say just above the button what it is for?

Comment: OneDrive say that it can't download files which "may" due to this setting, come to this setting and nothing blocked :(

Answer (score 4):

When this button is greyed out, it means you have not blocked any apps from requesting automatic file downloads.  I have not blocked apps from downloading file and my setting is greyed out as well.

See this article for assistance:

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/101977-allow-block-automatic-file-downloads-apps-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Answers are expected to quote and cite the relevant information from an external link, so in the event the reference link stops working, the answer remains relevant.  You should consider quoting and citing the relevant information from your link.